# Delphi syntax error in FROM clause but - there's no FROM clause

Tags: sql, syntax-error, delphi-2010

I'm using the insert function in SQL code for Delphi. The program compiles and runs however, upon clicking the button which executes the insert function I receieve a message saying

> Syntax error in FROM clause.

Upon breaking the program, it highlights the last line of code before `end`. If I were to remove that line of code and re-run the program, I am greeted with the same error and upon breaking it highlights the `end;` of the buttonclick procedure.

Please keep in mind that I am still a student and a novice to this language.

```
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('insert into FPS_Tbl([MatchID],[kills],[standings],[GrenadeKill],[TimePlayed],[Username],[Comments],[Headshots],[Dates])');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('values("'+IntToStr(ids)+'","'+IntToStr(Kills)+'","'+standings+'","'+IntToStr(grenKills)+'","'+times+'","'+user+'","'+comment+'","'+IntToStr(HedShots)+'","'+DateToStr(Now)+'");');
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

end;
recalls;
```

`recalls` is a procedure for displaying the contents of the table in a Richedit.

Not really sure as to why I am getting this error as there is no 'From' clause in my SQL statements. To those who do assist Thank you very much.

Comment: Be aware of SQL injection!

Comment: apologies i am not aware of what sql injection is but i have found the reason as to why it was not working...but my thanks for your input

Comment: Have a look [here](http://bobby-tables.com/) for details about the serious security issue. Certainly unrelated to the question, but worth a look at.

Comment: In this case your FROM clause is actually the VALUES list. I think the values should be surrounded by single and not double quotes independently of the DBMS, so try that - and in this case you need to know how to escape the single quotes inside the Add method, or try to use double quotes there.

Comment: Why you are using `Add()` there? Since you don't clear the `Tstrings` there, it will always add an `INSERT` statement to another and so on. And please **use parameters** instead of concatenationa string. And why `recalls;` is after the `end;`?

Comment: i had realised that i needed to clear the sql beforehand so once i did the profram ran fine and the values were dded but thank you guys for  the input. the recalls is after the end because that specific end is for a with statement.

Comment: Do not concatenate user input into a SQL string like that use a PreparedStatement. https://wiki.freepascal.org/Working_With_TSQLQuery

Answer (score 0):

try to insert simple space to separate (last word in first add) and (first word in second add), may like so:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(' values("'+IntToStr(ids)+'","'+IntToStr(Kills)+'","'+standings+'","'+IntToStr(grenKills)+'","'+times+'","'+user+'","'+comment+'","'+IntToStr(HedShots)+'","'+DateToStr(Now)+'");');
```

Answer (score 0):

When invoking a multi-line SQL query, you need to `Clear()` the `SQL` before you then `Add()` lines to it, otherwise you will be adding on to a *previous* query:

```pascal
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear; // <-- ADD THIS!!!
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('insert into FPS_Tbl([MatchID],[kills],[standings],[GrenadeKill],[TimePlayed],[Username],[Comments],[Headshots],[Dates])');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('values("' + IntToStr(ids) + '","' + IntToStr(Kills) + '","' + standings + '","' + IntToStr(grenKills) + '","' + times + '","' + user + '","' + comment + '","' + IntToStr(HedShots) + '","' + DateToStr(Now) + '");');
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Otherwise, use the `Text` property instead:

```pascal
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'insert into FPS_Tbl([MatchID],[kills],[standings],[GrenadeKill],[TimePlayed],[Username],[Comments],[Headshots],[Dates]) values("' + IntToStr(ids) + '","' + IntToStr(Kills) + '","' + standings + '","' + IntToStr(grenKills) + '","' + times + '","' + user + '","' + comment + '","' + IntToStr(HedShots) + '","' + DateToStr(Now) + '");');
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

That said, your code is subject to an [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) attack.  You can avoid that by using [`AnsiQuotedStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiQuotedStr) for all string inputs:

```pascal
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('insert into FPS_Tbl([MatchID],[kills],[standings],[GrenadeKill],[TimePlayed],[Username],[Comments],[Headshots],[Dates])');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('values("' + IntToStr(ids) + '","' + IntToStr(Kills) + '",' + AnsiQuotedStr(standings,'"') + ',"' + IntToStr(grenKills) + '",' + AnsiQuotedStr(times,'"') + ',' + AnsiQuotedStr(user,'"') + ',' + AnsiQuotedStr(comment,'"') + ',"' + IntToStr(HedShots) + '","' + DateToStr(Now) + '");');
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Or better, by using a [parameterized query](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries) instead:

```pascal
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('insert into FPS_Tbl([MatchID],[kills],[standings],[GrenadeKill],[TimePlayed],[Username],[Comments],[Headshots],[Dates])');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('values(:PId,:PKills,:PStandings,:PGrenKills,:PTimes,:PUser,:PComment,:PHeadShots,:PDate);');
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PId').Value := IntToStr(ids);
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PKills').Value := IntToStr(Kills);
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PStandings').Value := standings;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PGrenKills').Value := IntToStr(grenKills);
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PTimes').Value := times;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PUser').Value := user;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PComment').Value := comment;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PHeadShots').Value := IntToStr(HedShots);
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PDate').Value := DateToStr(Now);
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```